# Best way to call COM wrappers from JavaScript in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, wrapper

My application uses Internet Explorer (we're required to support IE8 still) to call certain wrappers that often create modal windows for users.

We've come across an error due to the JavaScript statements stacking up while the user uses these wrappers. It's text is the following:

> Stop running this script?
>
> A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it
>   continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

I've found Microsoft's solution [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175500), but that wouldn't work for us. Modifying the registry isn't a good solution, because we want this safety net.

What seems to be happening is the JavaScript is hung up on the call to the COM wrappers and there are reoccurring auto-refreshes every minute that fill up the stack. I'm wondering if there is a way for the COM wrapper to be called without disabling these auto-refreshes.

I imagine that calling the wrappers with a "setTimeout" would allow the browser to finish any processes before calling the wrapper, but that would still hang up the thread until the wrapper was finished.

Are there any ways I can have Internet Explorer call a wrapper without JavaScript? Or maybe in another JavaScript thread? Again, the ideal solution would allow the webpage to continue to auto-refresh without being hung up from the call to the wrapper.

Comment: For the most part, you can't call COM interfaces from JavaScript.  COM is meant for browser helper objects or extensions written in C++.  Without more info, useful suggestions are hard.  Your use of modal operations may be why the script is "stacking."  By definition, modal dialogs pause the calling script until the dialog is dealt with.  Perhaps you can rework things so that the modal dialogs do not occur during a sequential series of statements, perhaps by using a form to collect data from the user and firing the sequential process once the information is fully collected.

Comment: Yeah... It's a very weird architecture. And my company probably forbids me from being any more specific. Sadly your suggestion isn't an option we could use.

I think IE10's workers would be the best solution, but we also have to support IE8...

Comment: You have to use IE8, you can't change the registry, your archictecture is weird, but you must keep it, plus it's forbidden to talk about it. Nobody can help you here, dude :-)

Comment: The IE warning is about too many JS statements without returning to the top-level, so I find it hard to believe it happens due to a COM call.  The page you mention even states: "*the time-out dialog box does not display during ActiveX control or database-access delays*".  I've done calls from IE JS to COM objects that display modal windows too, and I never saw this message due to the delay.  You suggest using `setTimeout` to call the wrapper, which tells me you're doing a lengthy loop in JS to start with, which doesn't return to the top-level timely, so you might be right about that approach.